# Reading data with TIdUDPServer

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-7, indy

I would like to read data from an electronic device that sends data to my PC by UDP. I have programmed a UDP server in Delphi. An exception occurs in class EIdSocketError (Failure #10049). Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   IdUDPServer1.Bindings.add.IP := '192.168.1.1';  //Electronic device ip
   IdUDPServer1.Bindings.add.Port:= 49152;         //Electronic device port   
   IdUDPServer1.OnUDPRead:= UDPRead;
   IdUDPServer1.Active:=True;

end;

procedure TForm1.UDPRead (Sender: TObject; AData: TStream; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
   bytes_received: integer;
begin
   bytes_received:=AData.size;
end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to assign the result of IdUDPServer1.Bindings.add to a variable and then set its IP and Port. If I remember correctly what you are doing is adding two bindings, one with IP and one with Port.

Comment: I have changed the code as follow, but the error is the same... I am supposing that binding ip must be the ip of the electronic device (not the PC ip): ***var
myaddress:TIdSocketHandle;
begin
   myaddress:=IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add;
   myaddress.IP:= '192.168.1.1';
   myaddress.Port:=49152;
   IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP:=myaddress.IP;
   IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add.Port:=myaddress.Port;
end;***

Comment: No, with Bindings you can specify on which ethernet adapter you are listening for UDP packets.

Comment: I have changed the bind ip address to '0.0.0.0' (and also '127.0.0.1'), but I continue receiving no data from the external device... Is there any bug in my code?

Comment: Please update your question with the latest code you are using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Keith Miller stated, you are misusing the `Bindings` property.  You are adding **2** bindings to the server - one for `192.168.1.1` on port `0` and another for `0.0.0.0` on port `49152`.  You need to call `Bindings.Add()` only once for each IP/Port pair you want to bind to, eg:

```
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle

Binding := IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add;
Binding.IP := ...;
Binding.Port := ...;
```

Or:

```
with IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add do
begin
  IP := ...;
  Port := ...;
end;
```

If you set the `DefaultPort` property ahead of time, then you can simplify the above to this:

```
IdUDPServer1.DefaultPort := ...;
IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := ...;
```

With that said, socket error 10049 is `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`, which means you are using the wrong IP address in the first place.  You need to specify an IP that belongs to the PC that `TIdUDPServer` is running on - the IP that the device will be sending UDP packets to.  You can either bind to the single wildcard IP `0.0.0.0` (or just a blank string ''), which tells `TIdUDPServer` to bind to all available local IPs:

```
IdUDPServer1.DefaultPort := ...;
IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := ''; // or: '0.0.0.0'
```

Or you can use Indy's `GStack.LocalAddresses` property to determine the locally available IPs and create separate `Bindings` for them individually as needed.

```
IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
IdUDPServer1.DefaultPort := ...;

with GStack.LocalAddresses do
begin
  for I := 0 to Count-1 do
    IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := Strings[I];
end;
```

**Update:** if you bind the server to port 0 to let the OS pick a port, you can discover what port was selected by looking at the `TIdSocketHandle.Port` property after the server was activated:

```
var
  Binding: TIdSocketHandle
  ListeningPort: TIdPort;

IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Clear;

Binding := IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add;
Binding.IP := ...;
Binding.Port := 0;
{
or: 
IdUDPServer1.DefaultPort := 0;
Binding := IdUDPServer1.Bindings.Add;
Binding.IP := ...;
}

IdUDPServer1.Active := True;

ListeningPort := Binding.Port;
```

Comment: I will make modifications in my code and I will show you my results